# Jquery slideUp doesn't work at first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created myself a accordion menu, but I've got a problem. When I click for the first time on 'li' element slideUp doesn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu ul li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
      if ($(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $(this).next().slideUp();
        $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
      } else {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
      }
    } else {
      $('#menu ul li').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      });
      $('#menu ul li ul').slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideDown();
      $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#menu,
#menu ul,
#menu li,
#menu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
}

#menu a {
  line-height: 1.3;
}

#menu > ul > li {
  margin: 0;
}

#menu > ul > li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

#menu > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
  padding: 5px;
}

#menu > ul > li > a > span {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#menu > ul > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #0074a2 url('../img/icons/menuActive.png') no-repeat 101%;
}

#menu > ul > li.active {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#menu > ul > li.active > a {
  background: #0074a2 url('../img/icons/menuActive.png') no-repeat 101%;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
}


/* Sub menu */

#menu ul ul {
  padding: 5px 12px;
  display: none;
  background: #333333;
}

#menu ul ul li {
  padding: 3px 0;
}

#menu ul ul a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

#menu ul ul a:hover {
  color: #0074a2;
}

#menu ul li.active ul {
  display: block;
}

#menu ul li img {
  float: left;
  margin: -2px 4px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class='has-sub active'><a href='#'><span>AAA</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'><span>AAA_1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>AAA_2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>AAA_3</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>BBB</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'><span>BBB_1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>BBB_2</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class='has-sub last'><a href='#'><span>CCC</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'><span>CCC_1</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>CCC_2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>CCC_3</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>CCC_4</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my simple code typed in jsfiddle.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/60qL5vx1/)

Could anyone tell me where is an error and how to solve it ?

Thanks !

Comment: whats not working :/ ?

Comment: when you click first time on any 'li' element it doesn't slideUp, only dissapear. Next clicks works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The state of the html goes like this: 
 1. From start: `<ul>`
 2. After you click once: `<ul style="display: none;">`
 3. After you click it again: `<ul style="display: block;">`

Now I'm not that great when it comes to css, but if you keep track of the dynamic css which goes on when you press it, then you'll know what attributes you are missing on your styling.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `active` class has been removed before finishing `slideUp` animation. Use `setTimeout` function like following.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $(this).parent().removeClass('active')
}, 0);
```

You can increase time if you need.

**Update:**

I think your selector should be.

```
$('#menu > ul > li > a')
```

instead of

```
$('#menu ul li a')
```